# How can I work on asp.net mvc on MacBook in a M1 chipset?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, apple-m1

all the library files to be installed in visual studio preview 4 or in a community. not able to create a webform in asp.net. it is not recognising the extension .aspx in visual studio preview 4

Comment: you can use visual studio code with MVC extension.

Comment: You should be out of luck, as WebForms never made it to .Net Core and is not availalbe on platforms other then Windows. But you should clarify your question: is this about WebForms or MVC?